# Inefficient memory usage while dealing with strings read from a text file

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have a large file - about 1.7 GB - consisting of 25 million lines with each line in the following format : text, number.

The thing is the text could be same in multiple lines i.e.

I am a boy, 34

..

..

I am a boy, 56

I am reading each line of the file in a while loop and putting the string and number in a hashmap.

Code :

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.txt");

InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream);

while(true)
{
    line =reader.readLine();
    if (line == null) 
    {
        break;
    }
    String text= line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(",")).trim();

    String id = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(",") + 1).trim();

    hm.put(text,id);
}
```

where hm is a hashmap.

The reason I am using **substring** and **lastIndexOf** is because the text might have comma itself.

My question is : am I using too many Strings? Are the duplicate strings extracted from the text file going to remain in memory as copies or only one of them will be present. Is there a way (using intern method of strings or something ) to reduce the number of strings used.When I use Eclipse MAT for analysing memory usage, it shows about 9 GB of Heap Space used.

Comment: Even using intern, you create the intermediate strings prior to interning; and once they're interned, they are never gc'd.

Comment: @AndyTurner But if there are multiple strings, only one of them will have the intermediate form created and put in the heap, right ?

Comment: The duplicate strings will be garbage collected, because they're not stored in the hash map. By the way, your code doesn't make a lot of sense. That `while` loop will empty the file and `line` will be `null` when you get to the first `substring` call. So it shouldn't be using any memory at all.

Comment: @JimMischel I have edited the code.

Comment: My mistake. I mis-read your code. I've formatted it so others won't make the same mistake I did.

Comment: Sounds fine to me. Java Garbage Collection might be lazy if you have a very large MaxHeapSize and depending on the Java implementation. Also pre-Java 9 you may save some memory if the strings use the Latin alphabet by using: `XX:+CompactStrings` but there is still work on the way to make Java object (headers) smaller.